# Draw a line between two tikz plots with Overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, overlays

I want to draw lines between two tikz plots using overlay. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, remember picture]
\pgfplotsset{scale only axis}

\begin{axis}[       
    axis lines=left, 
    samples=100,
    ymax = 2.3]

    \addplot[color = black][domain=0:2] {x};
    \node[draw,black] (a) at (axis cs: 1, 1.5){};   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,remember picture]
\definecolor{mathblue}{rgb}{0,0.28,0.55 }
    \pgfplotsset{scale only axis}
    \begin{axis}[       
        axis lines=left, 
        samples=100,
        ymax = 2.3
        ]

        \addplot[color = black][domain=0:2] {x};
        \node[draw,black] (A) at (axis cs: 1,1.5 ) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[dashed,gray] (a) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, in the output the connecting line between (a) and (A) is at a completely wrong position and I don't find my mistake. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* need to use the `scale` key, use it in the axis, not the ambient `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ remember picture]
\pgfplotsset{scale only axis}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.6,       
    axis lines=left, 
    samples=100,
    ymax = 2.3]

    \addplot[color = black][domain=0:2] {x};
    \node[draw,black] (a) at (axis cs: 1, 1.5){};   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\definecolor{mathblue}{rgb}{0,0.28,0.55 }
    \pgfplotsset{scale only axis}
    \begin{axis}[scale=0.6,       
        axis lines=left, 
        samples=100,
        ymax = 2.3
        ]

        \addplot[color = black][domain=0:2] {x};
        \node[draw,black] (A) at (axis cs: 1,1.5 ) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[dashed,gray] (a) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, there should not be much need for using `scale` in pgfplots, you can use the `width` and `height` keys.

Comment: Perfekt. It works fine now. Thank you.